# Write program which only accepts certain letters in java (exception handling)

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to create a program in Java that writes a line of characters, but only certain characters which in this case is "a" or "b". How would I do this?

Right now it writes "ababbbabbaab", but if it writes "oohmtkgfgk" for example, it needs to throw an exception.

```
public class Writer {
    public void writer() {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("FSA.txt", true);
            writer.write("ababbbabbaab");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the contents before writing to ensure they only contain the wanted letters.

Comment: Create a subclass of FileWriter, override the `write()` method to first check if the contents are within the set you expect, and if it succeeds then call `super.write()`, otherwise through your own custom exception, or some other general `IOException`

Comment: `if (the string contains the wrong letters) throw new SomeKindOfException(message);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex **^[ab]*$** to validate the string instead of splitting and iterating. Saves lines of code. This regex validates whether the text contains only characters inside [], in your case a&b.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("FSA.txt", true);
            String str = "ababbbabbaabc";
            validate(str);
            writer.write(str);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
}

private static void validate(String string) throws IOException {
    if(!string.matches("^[ab]*$"))
      throw new IOException();             
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a method and verify if **a** or **b** are present in the string to be stored

## Example

```
 // If the 'a' or 'b'are  present in string, it returns the index(>=0). 
//If not, it returns -1. So, a non-negative return value means that 'a' is
    // present in the string.
    private boolean checkText(String string) {
        final int aIndex = string.indexOf('a');
        final int bIndex = string.indexOf('b');
        if (aIndex!=-1 && bIndex!=-1) {
         return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and check that all letters are a or b, if not throw a exception.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("FSA.txt", true);
            String str = "ababbbabbaabc";
            checkText(str);
            writer.write(str);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
}

private static void checkText(String string) throws IOException {
    for(String str: string.split("")) {
        if(str.equals("")) continue;
        if(!str.equals("a") && !str.equals("b")) throw new IOException();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!